# Software to build networks visualization using relational tables

Tags: open-source, data-visualization, sql-server, social-networks

I've an table in SQL Server with the following schema:

```
 - Partner_ID
 - Child_ID
 - Relationship_Name
```

Example of my data:

```
Partner_ID  Child_ID    Relationship_Name
A             A1            Normal
B             B1            Custom
B             B2            Custom
A1           AAA            Custom
B1           B1.1           Normal
B2            BBB           Normal
```

I want to draw a network visualization (like the charts that we can do using Gephi) using the table as input.

There exists any open source tool that allows me to make this implementation?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Could you give more details about what you need, output formats, main features and the like? Right now I think there are many possibilities, hence it's too broad to answer.

Comment: @Alejandro I only want to see the relationships on a display hierarchical structure. I don't want to add any strenght to the relationship only to know if the fields are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in R:

```
# some newer libraries for dealing with networks
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
theme_set(theme_void())

#read in data
txt <- read.table(text = "
Partner_ID Child_ID Relationship_Name
A A1 Normal
B B1 Custom
B B2 Custom
A1 AAA Custom
B1 B1.1 Normal
B2 BBB Normal", 
header=TRUE, sep=" ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# table (data frame) to graph object
gr <- as_tbl_graph(txt)


#plot it
ggraph(gr,layout="nicely")+
        geom_edge_link(colour="blue",alpha=0.3)+
        geom_node_point()+
        geom_node_text(aes(label=name),size=4,repel=T)
```

Result:

[image]